# can you see the codes generated by the app inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I saw app inventor and have tried it and thought "wow this could really make app development more easy".

But it does have some downside: some people have a problem with the apps created on app inventor not running correctly on their phone, while it runs on the emulator.

And there are also news like you can't upload apps created on app inventor to your android market account, so i just thought it would be really helpful if you could see the codes generated by app inventor like in eclipse.

If you use the GUI for the xml it generates a code and since app inventor is also in java it should also have a way the user can see the codes generated by the app inventor and use it as a reference for coding in eclipse or other java IDE.

So is their a way to see the codes generated or not?

Comment: Fixed your layout a bit. Please consider using the humble `.` more, and some paragraphing, as it was a bit a "wall of text" the way you posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Inventor does not generate Java code.  It generates Scheme code, which is converted by the Kawa compiler into byte code.  While you could undex and decompile it, as mentioned by cypressious, that code is unlikely to be useful.

There is a third-party program, [Marketizer](http://www.taiic.com/marketizer/), that prepares App Inventor apps for the market.

Answer (score 1):

If it generates an apk, you can unpack and then "undex" it via http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/. Then you can see the rough code by using tools like http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui.